# Gulp - AutoPrefixer not working as expected

Tags: css, npm, sass, gulp

I am using Gulp within my project, and want to use the autoprefixer.

My current gulp file is as follows:

```
    // Include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');
 // Include plugins
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var cache = require('gulp-cache');


 // Concatenate & Minify JS
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('js/*.js')
      .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
});


 gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return sass('scss/style.scss', {style: 'compressed'})
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
});




 gulp.task('images', function() {
  return gulp.src('images/**/*')
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 5, progressive: true, interlaced: true })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/img'));
});


 gulp.task('watch', function() {
   // Watch .js files
  gulp.watch('js/*.js', ['scripts']);
   // Watch .scss files
  gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', ['sass']);
   // Watch image files
  gulp.watch('images/*', ['images']);
 });


// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'sass', 'images', 'watch']);
```

As you can see, I have a .sass task, which works as expected. I have now added

```
.pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
        cascade: false
    }))
```

before it is minifed into a min.css file. Now, when I run this, all seems fine. But for example, when I save this code:

```
 .test{
    transform: scale(.5);
}
```

Id expect to have the -webkit- versions etc added into my min.css file, but for some reason it doesn't. Does anyone have an idea where the mistake could be?

Comment: does it never add the -webkit-prefix? Maybe some rules don't need the prefix for the last 2 browser-versions...

Comment: It just doesn't add anything but transform: scale(.5);

Comment: The autoprefixer uses the database from caniuse.com. On caniuse says that the last 2 versions of the browser does not support the "-webkit-" prefix. If you need to support some really old prefixes then enter last 40 versions, or something like that. Last supported versions: caniuse.com/#search=transform%3A%20scale

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. It works perfectly for me.

```
.pipe(autoprefixer({
   browsers: ['last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 6', 'ie 7', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4']
}))
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.